# Node JS. Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm working in a project using NodeJS and trying to create a JSON file with some data but fs (filesystem) does not seem to work, I've seen many people have had the same problem and I already watch the answers to them but none worked for me, I'm runnig my project in a NodeJS server using nodemon, I installed requirejs, I also installed **browserify** but I'm still having the same error, I apologize if it's a super fool error that I'm not watching, I would really apreciate your help c: (I already tried using *const fs = require('fs');* before my function.

Here's my app.js where require works:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('./css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))
app.use('./js', express.static(__dirname + 'public/js'))
app.use('./img', express.static(__dirname + 'public/img'))

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.info(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

and here's my weather.js that does not work

```
const api_key = config.API_KEY_WEATHER

async function calcWeather(){ 
    const info = await fetch('../js/data.json') // fetch editable c:
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    });
    for (var i in info) {
        const lat = info[i][0].latjson;
        const long = info[i][0].lonjson;
        const base = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${api_key}&units=metric&lang=sp`;
        
        fetch(base)
        .then((responses) => {
        return responses.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            var myObject = {  
                Latitud: data.coord.lat,
                Longitud: data.coord.lon,
                Temperatura: data.main.temp, 
                Ciudad: data.name, 
                Humedad: data.main.humidity,
                Descripcion: data.weather[0].description,
            };
            // convert JSON object to a string
            const fs = require('fs');
            const _myObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);
            // write file to disk
            fs.writeFile('../js/data2.json', _myObject, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`File is written successfully!`);
                }

            });
        });
        
    }
    
};
```

Here's how I send my data in my ejs (all my files are in the public folder)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/config.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/distancematrix.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/map.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/weather.js"></script>
<script src="requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Comment: What happens if you move the `const fs = require('fs');` to the top of the file? I've not developed in NodeJS for a while but having that statement in the middle of the code looks odd to me.

Comment: Do you have `"type": "module"` in you `package.json`,  require is a commonJS loader, if you have type module, node is going to use ESM loader instead.

Comment: If I move ```const fs = require('fs')``` I have another reference error :c

Comment: I don't have ```"type": "module"```in my ```package.json```

Comment: Or is the file extension `.ejs` and not `.js`..  Also have you tried it without nodemon first?

Comment: @Keith what do you mean with the file extension? I tried it without nodemon and I get the same error :c

Comment: Hang on a sec, `weather.js`  your using this in the browser, you can't use node's `fs` in the browser, you can only use `fs` at the server end..

Comment: @Keith mate, how can I use it in a server instead of the browser? I don't have so much knowledge in NodeJS :c

Comment: Is there a reason your storing the data in the first place?, from the browser you could just store using localeStorage, if you want to store on the server you will need your express app to expose a `post` handler, and you could send via that.  Alternatively you could also do the fetch at the server side, and then you can use `fs` to store the data, and then use an express `get` handler for the browser to use.

Comment: @Keith I'll try mate, thank you very much, I'll keep trying with browserify